# Como mudar o tamanho da font conforme digita

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Olá. sou iniciante em programação, tenho um projeto com JS onde criei um cartao dinamico que pega as informaçoes do input e espelha nele, porem queria controlar o tamanho da fonte para não quebrar, tipo caso a quatidade de caracteres for maior que 9 diminua a fonte para 10px (no css o fontSize tem 15px), caso apague a fonte voltara ao seu tamanho original

estava tentado com o seguinte codigo:

````
**Java Script**

 const ccName = document.querySelector(".cc-name .value")
ccName.innerText = firstname.value.length > 9 ? (ccName).style.fontSize="10px" : style.fontSize = "18px";
})


**HTML**


            <div class="name">
             <div class="cc-name">
            <div id="name"class="value">Fulano</div>
              </div> ```

porem não funciona muito bem, ao atingir 9 caracteres ele imprime "10px" e nada a mais, caso eu apague os caracteres ficam do tamaho da fonte que queria, mas ao atingir um numero superior a 9, volta a imprimir "10px".
Caso alguem puder me ajudar muito obrigada
````

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O seu código apresenta um erro, você está tentando mudar o conteúdo e não o tamanho da fonte, veja o exemplo a seguir de como deveria ser:
https://jsfiddle.net/gazefxwy/1/

```
function init(){
 console.log('debug 100');
 
const ccName = document.querySelector(".cc-name .value");
 ccName.style.fontSize = (ccName.innerText.length > 9) ?  "10px" :   "18px";
}
 
document.addEventListener("readystatechange", init);
```

Comment: Por falta de esclarecimento, pensei que **firstname** seria o input que não  foi incluído, quando digitado e quantidade de palavra atingisse 9 mudaria o tamanho MAS não dá para ter certeza... a ausência de trechos no código não dá muita margem para responder do que se trata o **firstname**

Comment: Oii, obrigada pelo seu tempo, testei e funcionou, muito obrigada!!! e desculpe a falta de trechos, sou nova na plataforma e não sei muito bem mexer, tentei editar isso ontem, mas não consegui kk  como meu projeto esta muito grande tentei pegar o trecho que precissava e esqueci de colocar o restante:      const firstname = document.querySelector("#firstname")
firstname.addEventListener("input", () => {
  const ccName = document.querySelector(".cc-name .value")
  ccName.innerText = firstname.value.length === 0 ? "Fulano" : firstname.value         esse era o restante do codigo

Comment: Eu fiz uma pequena correção no código que enviei na resposta, garanta que ele faça parte do seu código também. Aliás corrigi o seu post para ficar mais claro e fácil de ajudar outros desenvolvedores.

Comment: @EdsonVicenteCarliJunior muito obrigada novamente!!!